# PHP, авоисполнение скрипта на сервере

Tags: php

Господа, мое почтение. Дано: сервак, сайт, телеграм-бот(PHP), MySQL

У нас сайт для марафонов, активных участниц держим в БД и с ними взаимодействуем через бота - массовая рассылка, задания, пожелания и тд

Но хочется, что бы бот автоматически делал рассылку, без нашего (одминского) вмешательства

Архитектура в голове такая:

1. На серваке цикл с проверкой - не настал ли момент Х ?
2. Ежели настал, то берем из БД нужный контент и рассылаем юзрам

И вот реализовать такое очень легко имея некий элемент взаимодействия (кнопку на сайте, комманду в боте) - типа клац, и пошел процесс, а вот как сделать все это автоматически?

БД:
`id | time_x | content`

Основной вопрос, можно ли на серваке (php 7X) запустить бесконечный цикл со сравнением time_x с северным временем?

Можете написать псевдокодом, разберемси, хочу понять технологию)

Comment: а почему не воспользоваться cron для запуска раз в минуту, или 5, или 10...

Comment: Разумно, @splash58! Никогда еще не использовал планировщики! Спасибо!!) Есть что изучить))